# Формат вывода даты 01-01-2018

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая выводит дату через определенное кол-во дней:

```js
function get(data, day) {
  data = data.split('-');
  data = new Date(data[2], +data[1] - 1, +data[0] + day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  data = [data.getDate(), data.getMonth() + 1, data.getFullYear()];
  data = data.join('-').replace(/(^|\/)(\d)(?=\/)/g, "$10$2");
  return data
}
console.log(get("24-12-2018", 10));
```

Сейчас она выводит дату в формате `1-1-2018`, каким образом сделать вывод даты в формате **01-01-2018** ? то есть день и месяц с 0.
Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605214/javascript-add-leading-zeroes-to-date

Comment: Работу с датами очень удобно реализовать с библиотекой `moment.js`. https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по ответу вот отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605248, можно сделать так:

```js
function get(data, day) {
  data = data.split('-');
  data = new Date(data[2], +data[1] - 1, +data[0] + day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  data = [addZeroz(data.getDate()), addZeroz(data.getMonth() + 1), data.getFullYear()];
  data = data.join('-').replace(/(^|\/)(\d)(?=\/)/g, "$10$2");
  return data
}

function addZeroz(number) {
  return ('0' + number).slice(-2);
}

console.log(get("24-12-2018", 10));
```

То есть `.slice(-2)` всегда дает последние два символа из строки, поэтому если `getDate()` или `getMonth()` вернет однозначное число, то добавится (сконкатинируется) ноль вперед и вернется два числа. Если же в дате будет двузначное число, то не смотря на то, что сконкатинируется ноль - вернется все также последние два числа, то есть ноль отбросится.